# How to use a factory for DataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, factory

I would like to use the **DataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true** feature. Unfortunately, it seems to work only with concrete classes which have a default constructor. My collection of business objects doesn't provide a default constructor.

I'm looking for a way to register a factory that knows how to create the objects for the DataGrid. I had a look at the DataGrid and the ListCollectionView but none of them seems to support my scenario.

Answer (score 30):

The problem:

"I'm looking for a way to register a factory that knows how to create the objects for the DataGrid". (Because my collection of business objects doesn't provide a default constructor.)

The symptoms:

If we set `DataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true` and then bind a collection of items to the DataGrid where the item doesn't have a default constructor, then the DataGrid doesn't show a 'new item row'.

The causes:

When a collection of items is bound to any WPF ItemControl, WPF wraps the collection in either:

1. a [BindingListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx) when the collection being bound is a `BindingList<T>`.  `BindingListCollectionView` implements [IEditableCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.aspx) but doesn't implement `IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem`.
2. a [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) when the collection being bound is any other collection. `ListCollectionView` implements [IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionviewaddnewitem.aspx) (and hence `IEditableCollectionView`).

For option 2) the DataGrid delegates creation of new items to the `ListCollectionView`.  `ListCollectionView` internally tests for the existence of a default constructor and disables `AddNew` if one doesn't exist. Here's the relevant code from ListCollectionView using [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

```
public bool CanAddNewItem (method from IEditableCollectionView)
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.IsEditingItem)
      return !this.SourceList.IsFixedSize;
    else
      return false;
  }
}

bool CanConstructItem
{
  private get
  {
    if (!this._isItemConstructorValid)
      this.EnsureItemConstructor();
    return this._itemConstructor != (ConstructorInfo) null;
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to override this behaviour.

For option 1) the situation is a lot better.  The DataGrid delegates creation of new items to the BindingListView, which in turn delegates to [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx). `BindingList<T>` also checks for the existence of a default constructor, but fortunately `BindingList<T>` also allows the client to set the AllowNew property and attach an event handler for supplying a new item.  See *the solution* later, but here's the relevant code in `BindingList<T>`

```
public bool AllowNew
{
  get
  {
    if (this.userSetAllowNew || this.allowNew)
      return this.allowNew;
    else
      return this.AddingNewHandled;
  }
  set
  {
    bool allowNew = this.AllowNew;
    this.userSetAllowNew = true;
    this.allowNew = value;
    if (allowNew == value)
      return;
    this.FireListChanged(ListChangedType.Reset, -1);
  }
}
```

Non-solutions:

- Support by DataGrid (not available)

It would reasonable to expect the DataGrid to allow the client to attach a callback, through which the DataGrid would request a default new item, just like `BindingList<T>` above.  This would give the client the first crack at creating a new item when one is required.

Unfortunately this isn't supported directly from the DataGrid, even in .NET 4.5.

*.NET 4.5 does appear to have a new event 'AddingNewItem' that wasn't available previously, but this only lets you know a new item is being added.*

Work arounds:

- Business object created by a tool in the same assembly: use a partial class

This scenario seems very unlikely, but imagine that Entity Framework created its entity classes with no default constructor (not likely since they wouldn't be serializable), then we could simply create a partial class with a default constructor. Problem solved.

- Business object is in another assembly, and isn't sealed: create a super-type of the business object.

Here we can inherit from the business object type and add a default constructor.

This initially seemed like a good idea, but on second thoughts this may require more work than is necessary because we need to copy data generated by the business layer into our super-type version of the business object.

We would need code like

```
class MyBusinessObject : BusinessObject
{
    public MyBusinessObject(BusinessObject bo){ ... copy properties of bo }
    public MyBusinessObject(){}
}
```

And then some LINQ to project between lists of these objects.

- Business object is in another assembly, and is sealed (or not): encapsulate the business object.

This is much easier

```
class MyBusinessObject
{
    public BusinessObject{ get; private set; }

    public MyBusinessObject(BusinessObject bo){ BusinessObject = bo;  }
    public MyBusinessObject(){}
}
```

Now all we need to do is use some LINQ to project between lists of these objects, and then bind to `MyBusinessObject.BusinessObject` in the DataGrid.  No messy wrapping of properties or copying of values required.

**The solution: (hurray found one)**

- Use `BindingList<T>`

If we wrap our collection of business objects in a `BindingList<BusinessObject>` and then bind the DataGrid to this, with a few lines of code our problem is solved and the DataGrid will appropriately show a new item row.

```
public void BindData()
{
   var list = new BindingList<BusinessObject>( GetBusinessObjects() );
   list.AllowNew = true;
   list.AddingNew += (sender, e) => 
       {e.NewObject = new BusinessObject(... some default params ...);};
}
```

**Other solutions**

- implement IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem on top of an existing collection type.  Probably a lot of work.
- inherit from ListCollectionView and override functionality.  I was partially successful trying this, probably can be done with more effort.

Comment: Beware that others are reporting BindingList does not scale well http://www.themissingdocs.net/wordpress/?p=465

Comment: Great answer. Instead of using `ObservableCollection<T>` I just switched to `BindingList<T>` that actually does the same thing, and set `AllowNew` to `true` in its constructor.

Answer (score 7):

I've found another solution to this problem. In my case, my objects need to be initialized using a factory, and there isn't really any way to get around that.

I couldn't use `BindingList<T>` because my collection must support grouping, sorting, and filtering, which `BindingList<T>` does not support.

I solved the problem by using DataGrid's `AddingNewItem` event. This almost [entirely undocumented event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem.aspx) not only tells you a new item is being added, but also [*allows lets you choose which item is being added*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.addingnewitemeventargs.aspx). `AddingNewItem` fires before anything else; the `NewItem` property of the `EventArgs` is simply `null`.

Even if you provide a handler for the event, DataGrid will refuse to allow the user to add rows if the class doesn't have a default constructor. However, bizarrely (but thankfully) if you do have one, and set the `NewItem` property of the `AddingNewItemEventArgs`, it will never be called.

If you choose to do this, you can make use of attributes such as `[Obsolete("Error", true)]` and `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` in order to make sure no one ever invokes the constructor. You can also have the constructor body throw an exception

Decompiling the control lets us see what's happening in there.

```
private object AddNewItem()
{
  this.UpdateNewItemPlaceholder(true);
  object newItem1 = (object) null;
  IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem collectionViewAddNewItem = (IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem) this.Items;
  if (collectionViewAddNewItem.CanAddNewItem)
  {
    AddingNewItemEventArgs e = new AddingNewItemEventArgs();
    this.OnAddingNewItem(e);
    newItem1 = e.NewItem;
  }
  object newItem2 = newItem1 != null ? collectionViewAddNewItem.AddNewItem(newItem1) : this.EditableItems.AddNew();
  if (newItem2 != null)
    this.OnInitializingNewItem(new InitializingNewItemEventArgs(newItem2));
  CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
  return newItem2;
}
```

As we can see, in version `4.5`, the DataGrid does indeed make use of `AddNewItem`. The contents of `CollectionListView.CanAddNewItem` are simply:

```
public bool CanAddNewItem
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.IsEditingItem)
      return !this.SourceList.IsFixedSize;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

So this doesn't explain why we we still need to have a constructor (even if it is a dummy) in order for the add row option to appear. I believe the answer lies in some code that determines the visibility of the `NewItemPlaceholder` row using `CanAddNew` rather than `CanAddNewItem`. This might be considered some sort of bug.

Comment: I've been struggling with the exact same problem, and was digging through  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs.html, and found that there is a CoerceCanUserAddRows which looks at CanAddNew rather than CanAddNewItem. I would agree that this should be considered a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I had a look at [IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionviewaddnewitem%28VS.100%29.aspx) and it seems to be adding this functionality.

From MSDN

> The IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem
>   interface enables application
>   developers to specify what type of
>   object to add to a collection. This
>   interface extends
>   IEditableCollectionView, so you can
>   add, edit, and remove items in a
>   collection.
>   IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem adds
>   the AddNewItem method, which takes an
>   object that is added to the
>   collection. This method is useful when
>   the collection and objects that you
>   want to add have one or more of the
>   following characteristics:
>
> - The objects in the CollectionView are different types.
> - The objects do not have a default constructor.
> - The object already exists.
> - You want to add a null object to the collection.

Although at [Bea Stollnitz blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=24), you can read the following

> - The limitation of not being able to add a new item when the source has no
>     default constructor is very well
>     understood by the team. WPF 4.0 Beta 2
>     has a new feature that brings us a
>     step closer to having a solution: the
>     introduction of
>     IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem
>     containing the AddNewItem method. You
>     can read the MSDN documentation about
>     this feature. The sample in MSDN shows
>     how to use it when creating your own
>     custom UI to add a new item (using a
>     ListBox to display the data and a
>     dialog box to enter the new item).
>     From what I can tell, DataGrid doesn’t
>     yet use this method though (although
>     it’s a bit hard to be 100% sure
>     because Reflector doesn’t decompile
>     4.0 Beta 2 bits).

That answer is from 2009 so maybe it's usable for the DataGrid now

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. The ListCollectionView class implements the IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem interface. I had a look at the implementation via Reflector. Microsoft did a lot performance optimizations in this class. I don't want to implement this interface for myself just to use a factory method.

Comment: @jbe. I understand that :) Also, there weren't alot of information on IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem, atleast not that I was able to find. Be sure to update if you find a way to accomplish your task

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could suggest to provide wrapper for your class without default constructor, in which constructor for source class will be called.
For example you have this class without default constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Complicate class without default constructor.
/// </summary>
public class ComplicateClass
{
    public ComplicateClass(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Write a wrapper for it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper for complicated class.
/// </summary>
public class ComplicateClassWraper
{
    public ComplicateClassWraper()
    {
        _item = new ComplicateClass("def_name", "def_surname");
    }

    public ComplicateClassWraper(ComplicateClass item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public ComplicateClass GetItem() { return _item; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _item.Name; }
        set { _item.Name = value; }
    }
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _item.Surname; }
        set { _item.Surname = value; }
    }

    ComplicateClass _item;
}
```

Codebehind.
In your ViewModel you need to create wrapper collection for your source collection, which will handle item adding/removing in datagrid.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Prepare collection with complicated objects.
        _sourceCollection = new List<ComplicateClass>();
        _sourceCollection.Add(new ComplicateClass("a1", "b1"));
        _sourceCollection.Add(new ComplicateClass("a2", "b2"));

        // Do wrapper collection.
        WrappedSourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<ComplicateClassWraper>();
        foreach (var item in _sourceCollection)
            WrappedSourceCollection.Add(new ComplicateClassWraper(item));

        // Each time new item was added to grid need add it to source collection.
        // Same on delete.
        WrappedSourceCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Items_CollectionChanged);

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            foreach (ComplicateClassWraper wrapper in e.NewItems)
                _sourceCollection.Add(wrapper.GetItem());
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            foreach (ComplicateClassWraper wrapper in e.OldItems)
                _sourceCollection.Remove(wrapper.GetItem());
    }

    private List<ComplicateClass> _sourceCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<ComplicateClassWraper> WrappedSourceCollection { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, XAML code:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SecondName"  Binding="{Binding Path=Surname}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You don't even need a wrapper.  You could just inherit from the existing class and provide a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to provide an alternate solution to using a BindingList. In my situtation, the Business objects was held in an IEntitySet in a portable project (Silverlight), which did not support IBindingList.

The solution, first and foremost, is to subclass the grid, and overwrite the coerce callback for CanUserAddRows to use IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem:

```
public class DataGridEx : DataGrid
{
    static DataGridEx()
    {
        CanUserAddRowsProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, null, CoerceCanUserAddRows));
    }

    private static object CoerceCanUserAddRows(DependencyObject sender, object newValue)
    {            
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        var canAddValue= (bool)newValue;

        if (canAddValue)
        {
            if (dataGrid.IsReadOnly || !dataGrid.IsEnabled)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (dataGrid.Items is IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem v && v.CanAddNewItem == false)
            {
                // The view does not support inserting new items
                return false;
            }                
        }

        return canAddValue;
    }
}
```

And then use the *AddingNewItem* event to create the item:

```
dataGrid.AddingNewItem += (sender, args) => args.NewItem = new BusinessObject(args);
```

And if you care for the details, here is the reason why it is a problem in the first place. The coerce callback in the framework looks like this:

```
private static bool OnCoerceCanUserAddOrDeleteRows(DataGrid dataGrid, bool baseValue, bool canUserAddRowsProperty)
    {
        // Only when the base value is true do we need to validate that the user
        // can actually add or delete rows.
        if (baseValue)
        {
            if (dataGrid.IsReadOnly || !dataGrid.IsEnabled)
            {
                // Read-only/disabled DataGrids cannot be modified.
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((canUserAddRowsProperty && !dataGrid.EditableItems.CanAddNew) ||
                    (!canUserAddRowsProperty && !dataGrid.EditableItems.CanRemove))
                {
                    // The collection view does not allow the add or delete action
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return baseValue;
    }
```

You see how it gets the *IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew*? That means that it only enables adding when the view can insert ***and construct*** an item. The funny thing is that when we want to add a new item, it checks the *IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem.CanAddNewItem* instead, which only asks if the view supports inserting new items (not creating):

```
 object newItem = null;
        IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem ani = (IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem)Items;

        if (ani.CanAddNewItem)
        {
            AddingNewItemEventArgs e = new AddingNewItemEventArgs();
            OnAddingNewItem(e);
            newItem = e.NewItem;
        }
```