# What is the best way to force the WPF DataGrid to add a specific new item?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datacontract, itemssource, type-constraints

I have a `DataGrid` in a WPF application which has for its `ItemsSource` a custom collection that I wrote.  The collection enforces that all its items satisfy a certain requirement (namely they must be between some minimum and maximum values).

The collection's class signature is:

```
   public class CheckedObservableCollection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection,
                                            INotifyCollectionChanged
                                             where T : IComparable<T>, IEditableObject, ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I want to be able to use the `DataGrid` feature in which committing an edit on the last row in the `DataGrid` results in a new item being added to the end of the `ItemsSource`.

Unfortunately the `DataGrid` simply adds a new item created using the default constructor.  So, when adding a new item, `DataGrid` indirectly (through its `ItemCollection` which is a sealed class) declares:

```
ItemsSource.Add(new T())
```

where T is the type of elements in the CheckedObservableCollection.  I would like for the grid to instead add a different T, one that satisfies the constraints imposed on the collection.

My questions are: Is there a built in way to do this?  Has somebody done this already?  What's the best (easiest, fastest to code; performance is not an issue) way to do this?

Currently I just derived `DataGrid` to override the `OnExecutedBeginEdit` function with my own as follows:

```
public class CheckedDataGrid<T> : DataGrid where T : IEditableObject, IComparable<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable
{
  public CheckedDataGrid() : base() { }

  private IEditableCollectionView EditableItems {
     get { return (IEditableCollectionView)Items; }
  }

  protected override void OnExecutedBeginEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
     try {
        base.OnExecutedBeginEdit(e);
     } catch (ArgumentException) {
        var source = ItemsSource as CheckedObservableCollection<T>;
        source.Add((T)source.MinValue.Clone());
        this.Focus();
     }
  }
}
```

Where `MinValue` is the smallest allowable item in the collection.

I do not like this solution. If any of you have advice I would be very appreciative!

Thanks

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484256/how-to-use-a-factory-for-datagrid-canuseraddrows-true/9863828#9863828.  You can probably do what you need using a BindingList<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody interested, I ended up solving the problem by just deriving from `BindingList<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`, using my derived class as the `ItemsSource` in a regular `DataGrid`:

```
   public class CheckedBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private Predicate<T> _check;
  private DefaultProvider<T> _defaultProvider;

  public CheckedBindingList(Predicate<T> check, DefaultProvider<T> defaultProvider) {
     if (check == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("check cannot be null");
     if (defaultProvider != null && !check(defaultProvider()))
        throw new ArgumentException("defaultProvider does not pass the check");

     _check = check;
     _defaultProvider = defaultProvider;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Predicate the check item in the list against.
  /// All items in the list must satisfy Check(item) == true
  /// </summary>
  public Predicate<T> Check {
     get { return _check; }

     set {
        if (value != _check) {
           RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

           int i = 0;
           while (i < Items.Count)
              if (!value(Items[i]))
                 ++i;
              else
                 RemoveAt(i);

           RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
           SetProperty(ref _check, value, "Check");

           ResetBindings();
        }
     }
  }

  public DefaultProvider<T> DefaultProvider {
     get { return _defaultProvider; }
     set {
        if (!_check(value()))
           throw new ArgumentException("value does not pass the check");
     }
  }

  protected override void OnAddingNew(AddingNewEventArgs e) {
     if (e.NewObject != null)
        if (!_check((T)e.NewObject)) {
           if (_defaultProvider != null)
              e.NewObject = _defaultProvider();
           else
              e.NewObject = default(T);
        }

     base.OnAddingNew(e);
  }

  protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e) {
     switch (e.ListChangedType) {
        case (ListChangedType.ItemAdded):
           if (!_check(Items[e.NewIndex])) {
              RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
              RemoveItem(e.NewIndex);
              if (_defaultProvider != null)
                 InsertItem(e.NewIndex, _defaultProvider());
              else
                 InsertItem(e.NewIndex, default(T));
              RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
           }
           break;
        case (ListChangedType.ItemChanged):
           if (e.NewIndex >= 0 && e.NewIndex < Items.Count) {
              if (!_check(Items[e.NewIndex])) {
                 Items[e.NewIndex].CancelEdit();
                 throw new ArgumentException("item did not pass the check");
              }
           }
           break;
        default:
           break;
     }

     base.OnListChanged(e);
  }

  protected void SetProperty<K>(ref K field, K value, string name) {
     if (!EqualityComparer<K>.Default.Equals(field, value)) {
        field = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
  }
}
```

This class is incomplete, but the implementation above is enough for validating lists of statically-typed (not built by reflection or with the DLR) objects or value types.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is now semi-solvable under `4.5` using the `AddingNewItem` event of the `DataGrid`. [Here is my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776537/1333004).

> I solved the problem by using DataGrid's `AddingNewItem` event. This almost [entirely undocumented event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776537/1333004) not only tells you a new item is being added, but also [*allows lets you choose which item is being added*][2]. `AddingNewItem` fires before anything else; the `NewItem` property of the `EventArgs` is simply `null`.
>
> Even if you provide a handler for the event, DataGrid will refuse to allow the user to add
>   rows if the class doesn't have a default constructor. However, bizarrely (but thankfully) if you do have one, and set the `NewItem` property of the `AddingNewItemEventArgs`, it will never be called.
>
> If you choose to do this, you can make use of attributes such as `[Obsolete("Error", true)]` and `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` in order to make sure no one ever invokes the constructor. You can also have the constructor body throw an exception
>
> Decompiling the control lets us see what's happening in there...

Comment: Sadly my solution (the accepted answer) is still the only statically typed generic solution that fits the needs I had.  Event the newest version of WPF casts DataGrid items through object and trashes virtualization performance.  I know I said performance didn't matter, but I changed my mind.