# Intercepting DataGrid's Adding Event

Tags: wpf, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I'm trying to intercept the WPF datagrid's event for adding a new item. I need to set some properties on the data object which is inserted into the datasource. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by binding to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, then using the `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an event you can intercept. But you can probably do what you need with `BindingList<T>`.  See this [How to use a factory for DataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484256/how-to-use-a-factory-for-datagrid-canuseraddrows-true/9863828#9863828)