# Modify an item before it's added to a WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In the WPF DataGrid, when the user clicks or types on the last row, the datagrid automatically adds a new item to the ItemsSource collection using the default empty constructor for that type.

The problem is that the empty constructor for this type creates an object that is valid itself, but may not be valid in the context of the collection of other items. For example, lets say each row has a dropdown with a list of things. However, each thing can only be selected by one row. When the user adds a new item, I need to check all the other rows and make sure I don't set this value to something that is already selected. *This must happen before the item is added to the collection*, since there is some validation in the model which I cannot change.

Here is a simple example:

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ...

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ViewModel() { Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Column4 { get; set; }
}
```

When a new item is added, the default constructor is called and all the properties are null. Let's say this is a valid state for any single Item. However, when I put the items together in a collection, this is no longer valid. I need to set some values before the item is added to the collection.

Comment: Why not use a constructor in the `Item` class and set the values there?

Comment: You say this must happen before the item is added to the collection. Can you validate in the `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: One option would be to not let them add a row in the DataGrid itself. Have an add item button that pops open a window where they can fill in the details. You can pass along to this window the existing collection or just the info needed for your validation. Upon exiting the popup window, add this newly created item to your ObservableCollection<Item>.

Comment: @Elias The DataGrid control itself uses the default empty constructor, I don't have any control over that.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately that won't work since the collectionchanged event occurs after the collection is modified. I need to make changes before the collection is modified, and potentially prevent the change from occurring at all depending on the situation.

Comment: @LeeO. This is something I considered, but our customers are very picky about UI and rejected the idea.

Comment: I think this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484256/how-to-use-a-factory-for-datagrid-canuseraddrows-true/18776537#18776537